# Proposition 4.2 in Richard Bass' ''Real Analysis for Graduate Students''

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, proof-explanation

The following is from R. "Bass Real Analysis for Graduate Students" :

> **Proposition 4.2** *Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $\varnothing$ and $X$ are both in $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose $\ell:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$ with $\ell(\varnothing)=0$. Define*
> $$\mu^*(E)=\bigl\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ell(A_i):\ A_i\in\mathcal{C}\ \text{for each}\ i\ \text{and}\ E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\Bigr\}.\tag{4.1}$$
>
> *Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.*
>
> **Proof.** (1) and (2) of the definition of outer measure are obvious. To prove (3), let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be subsets of $X$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. For each $i$ there exist $C_{i1},C_{i2}\ldots\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A_i\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty C_{ij}$ and $\sum_j\ell(C_{ij})\leq\mu^*(A_i)+\varepsilon/2^i$. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\subset\bigcup_i\bigcup_jC_{ij}$ and
> \begin{align*}
> \mu^*\Bigl(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\Bigr) & \color{red}{\leq}\sum_{i,j}\ell(C_{ij})=\sum_i\Bigl(\sum_j\ell(C_{ij})\Bigr)\\
> & \leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu^*(A_i)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\varepsilon/2^i\\
> & =\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu^*(A_i)+\varepsilon.
> \end{align*}
> Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, $\mu^*(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu^*(A_i)$. $\qquad\square$

Where the red inequality comes from? There are two summations are on RHS of the red inequity how those two sums appears?

PS the book is [available](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Evictor/classes/ma5051/rags100514.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJy6fAkfvuAhU_SxUIHW29CAsQFjABegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw0PLp69LiQFLVf9r3uLQbPW) online.

Comment: It comes from the definition of $\mu^*$, because $\bigcup_i A_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i, j} C_{ij}$.

Comment: @zkutch please see page 36 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/classes/ma5051/rags100514.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJy6fAkfvuAhU_SxUIHW29CAsQFjABegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw0PLp69LiQFLVf9r3uLQbPW

Comment: I looked at it: electronic page $36$ on your link is same with paper page $20$ in book in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Book I looked:  Richard F. Bass - Real analysis for graduate students_ measure and integration theory-CreateSpace (2011).

We get circled inequality, because family of sets  $C_{ij}$ satisfy condition in definition of $\mu^*$, where $E=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$.

**Addition.**

This answer to second, added later question, about two sums in rhs: as $C_{ij}$ is countable cover of $E=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, then by definition of inf we have $\mu^*(E) \leqslant \sum_{i,j}l(C_{ij})$. Right side is absolute converged so we can write it as $\sum_{i,j}l(C_{ij})=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}C_{ij}$.

Comment: So how do you conclude the mentioned inequality in OP from $\mu^*(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) \le \mu^*( \bigcup_{i}\bigcup_{j} C_{ij}$) ?

Comment: Corrected answer and added last line.

Comment: There are two summations are on RHS of the red inequity! Could you be a little more descriptive? Two sentences in your answer, first one is a copy of what I wrote and the second is not helpful.

Comment: That two summations are same. First sentence is only name of book in which I looked to question. In second I mean that if in definition of $\mu^*$ you take in place of $E$ set $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, then $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)$ is inf with respect to all sums which covers $E$. One such is $\sum_{i,j}l(C_{ij})$. Is it helpful now?